# How to optimize my FASTA parser Python script in order to make it runs faster on slurm?

Tags: python, parsing, bioinformatics, fasta, genome

I hope I post on the right place ?
My script is running fine on little genomes but it take hours and days when it comes to work with mammal genomes. I tried many different things but Im out of idea. Can you tell me what cause this script to be so slow ? This script parse fasta file, it works with ID beginning with a > or not. It also calculates somes genomics metrics like N50 and L50 and finally it return a dict with seq IDs and their length.

Thank you very much!

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "N50 parser")

#parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="N50Parser.py", usage="N50")

parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", action="store", dest="input", required=True,
                    help="Input file with sequences")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", action="store", dest="output",
                    help="output file")
parser.add_argument("-o2", "--output2", action="store", dest="output2",
                    help="output file")


args = parser.parse_args()



def read_file(fasta_file):
    "Parse fasta file"
    descriptiondict = OrderedDict()
    dictionnary = OrderedDict()
    with open(fasta_file, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            record = line.strip()
            if record and record[0] == '>':
                seqid = record.split(" ")[0][1:]
                print(seqid)
                dictionnary[seqid] = ""
                toto = record.split(" ", 1)
                if len(toto) >= 2 :
                    description = toto[1]
                    descriptiondict[seqid] = description
                else:
                    descriptiondict[seqid] = ""
                continue
            dictionnary[seqid] += record

    return dictionnary, descriptiondict

seqdict, descriptdict = read_file(args.input)




lengthdict = OrderedDict()
for sequenceid in seqdict:
    lengthdict[sequenceid] = len(seqdict[sequenceid])



length = sum(lengthdict.values())


N_number = sum([seqdict[seqid].count("N") for seqid in seqdict])

print(N_number)
print(length)
all_len = sorted(lengthdict.values(), reverse=True)
print(all_len)

if length > 0:
    acum = 0

    for y in range (len(all_len)):
        if acum <= length / 2:
            acum = all_len[y] + acum
            n = y #L50
        else:
            break


    n = n + 1
    print("The L50 is", n)
    print("The N50 is", all_len[n-1])

with open(args.output, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("L50\t{}\n".format(n))
    outfile.write("N50\t{}\n".format(all_len[n-1]))


with open(args.output2, "w") as file:
    for key, value in lengthdict.items():
        file.write(f"{key} : {value}\n")
```

Comment: I don't immediately see why this would be slow. Use a profiler to figure out where most time is spent: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Comment: Ok thank you, i tried but nothing special comes out.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use well-established open source libraries for common tasks. In this case, use [Biopython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec12) to parse FASTA files, for example:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("ls_orchid.fasta", "fasta"):
    print(seq_record.id)
    print(repr(seq_record.seq))
    print(len(seq_record))
```

Install Biopython using `pip` or [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html):

```
conda create --channel bioconda --name biopython biopython
```

Comment: Yes I understand but Im steel a student and I have to perform some tasks with my "hand mad" fasta parser...